# CREATE TABLE (fusion tables) dynamically using FunctionTablesControls in APP Inventor 2

Tags: google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

I am trying to create dynamically a new Google fusion table with FusionTablesControl in App Inventor2. I set the ApiKey, KeyFile and ServiceAccountEmail. Additional  the UseServiceAuthentication is true.

I have some tables already created (manually in Google Drive) and could SELECT values from them perfectlly with the same parameters.

When I use the CREATE TABLE in the query, the event GOT RESULT  returns a Table ID correctly, meaning a sucessfully transaction I think... but the table is not really created, because after this and inmediatlly, I tried to make a SELECT on the supposed recently created table and return an error on the TableId.

I think that I am missing something, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see my answer in the [App Inventor forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/aymXu_cAlyM/a0Mr0gcOBAAJ)